# Publish by FTP, azure from appveyor error when site is running

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, appveyor

I have an error when I publish my dll from appveyor to azure by FTP, because the dll is current used by azure. When I stop my app on azure portal, there are no error.
The error message is for the dll:
The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)

How to deploy my application with not manual stop web site on azure before deploy with FTP from appveyor ?

Comment: A PC can only have one FTP application that uses the default port number for FTP which is port 20.  You either have to use a different port number of a different IP address.  You can't have two application using the same source IP, destination IP, and port number.  See webpage : https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/51f630b2-37c0-48a2-bbb0-ab35ceb6beef.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Deployment slot on your app.

With a deployment slot you can publish a new version, test it and if is correct swap with production slot.

Comment: Slot is best thing to do, but it is available starting from standard plan (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) as I see. So maybe restarted still be needed if site is on cheaper plan. To minimize downtime stop and start can be done with Azure PowerShell (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495288.aspx) in before and after deploy appveyor scripts - https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/#running-powershell-scripts-on-target-server-during-deployment